# Add enums to array and post to database

Tags: c#, enums

I have enums `GroupTypes` which I add to `Types` property.
There can be either Up/Down or both Up And Down types.
This is my code:

```
public enum GroupTypes: int {
  Down = 0,
  Up = 1,
}

[Column("types")]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "types")]
public GroupTypes[] Types {
  get;
  set;
}


// e.g.
var group = new Group() {
  Name = "Group",
    Types = new GroupTypes[] {
      GroupTypes.Up
    },
    OrganizationId = Organization.Id,
};
```

However when I post them to database I get 500 error.

It seems correct to me and I am not sure what goes wrong.

In my database the type for this column is: `"types" int4[] NULL` and I expect them to be saved as array ( [0,1] or [1] or [0])in the database . What I am misisng here?

Before adding types, post method worked fine so I am assuming they are the problem but it seems like I define them correctly. I am using DBeaver and PostgreSQL

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL there.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what database you are using.

Comment: I am using DBeaver and postgres

Comment: Do you know that you can use [Flag enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#enumeration-types-as-bit-flags) instead of enum arrays?

Answer (score 2):

It is usually a good idea to use [Flags enum & bitwise operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Your case should be like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum GroupTypes: 
{
  None = 0,
  Down = 1,
  Up = 2,
  DownAndUp = Down | Up
}
```

As a result, You need to save single value only instead of list of values.

Comment: If that's a [Flags] enum, then you shouldn't represent `UpAndown` like you did, they are represented by combining Down and Up into a single value.

Comment: Your's right. My mistaken. `DownAndUp`  instead of `UpAndDown`

Comment: You should use `{ None = 0, Down = 1, Up = 2, DownAndUp = Down | Up }`, because otherwise adding `Down` (being 0) to `Up` will make no difference. The flags (except `None` must have powers of 2). 1 = 2^0, 2 = 2^1, 4 = 2^2 ... You can write it as 1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 <<  2 ...

Comment: Yep, We should make it like you did.

Comment: Again, @Anonymous, using a number has much less semantic meaning than a single char. For instance, UpAndDown is stored as a 3 on the database, which is hard to decode without access and familiarity with the source code.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I wouldn't use an array to reflect that model. It'd be much better to use `Up`, `Down` and `Both`, for instance, otherwise you have to deal with the fact that it could be [1], [0], [1, 0], [0, 1], four combinations for the three states you need to present.

Also, this would map more elegantly to a database. In fact, I pretty much would use a character or even a whole string to represent that data, which gives more semantic value in the database (you already calling the column `type`, which is pretty generic.

```cs
public enum Types : char 
{
    Down = 'D',
    Up = 'U',
    Both = 'B',
}
```

---

With all that said, I haven't answered your question, because I need more information on the error you're getting and how you are communicating with the database.